# Rails Facebook login works on local environment but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

Facebook login works on my localhost but when I push the code to my server and try to login I get this error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: name):
app/models/confirmable.rb:20:in `initialize'
app/models/user.rb:83:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:5:in `facebook'
```

user.rb

```
 def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  if user
   return user
  else
   registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
   if registered_user
    return registered_user
   else
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                          provider:auth.provider,
                          uid:auth.uid,
                          email:auth.info.email,
                          password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                        )
   end

  end

 end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def facebook     
 @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)      
 if @user.persisted?       
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
 else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you share find_for_facebook_oauth method from Model User.

Comment: I added the user.rb and callbacks controller code in the above edit. Thanks

Comment: The user model does not have a name field. You're thinking that if I add that to the user model it will work? If that is that case, why does it currently work on localhost then?

Comment: Compare the database schema for development and production environment. If it's working in development then that means you have name field in users table But same is not true for production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems like there is no `name` attribute in `users` table.
While creating a user record you are passing the non-existing attribute and getting the error.

To resolve this issue,

Either add a column to users table called `name` By:

```
Generating a migration
  rails generate migration AddNameToUsers name:string
Running 
  rake db:migrate
```

Or

Remove the `name` attribute and value from list of arguments passed to `User.create`  method.